# SSRS conditional number formats

Tags: reporting-services, number-formatting

I have a report that shows an opening balance. If the balance is zero then I want to the number format #,0.00 to display as 0.00. However, if there is a credit then I want the number format #,0.00 C to display as, for example 123.45 c
I'm thinking it's some kind of Switch expression but for the life of me can't get it working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the format property to the expression below

`="#,0.00;#,0.00c;0.00"`

Comment: Thanks @niktrs though that's what I had before.

Comment: I have added format for zero but even without it, it should be the same as positive number format

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.